# RabbitMQ high watermark though, empty queue

Tags: rabbitmq

Below are two screenshots. One shows that RabbitMQ is entirely using his memory. The second the breakdown of the memory usage. The queue is empty, and as far as I know, RabbitMQ should not hold any messages as binaries when the queue is empty. Also, when killing al the consumers, the memory usages does drop a little bit but only by 0.2GB.

[image]

[image]

Comment: may I ask how many Connection do you have  and which version of rabbitmq are you using?

Comment: @basilisk max 120 connections and rabbitmq version  3.6.10

Comment: One thing you could try out is enabling background GC to see if it prevents this memory issue from happening again. Here is the relevant configuration:
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/rabbitmq_v3_6_15/docs/rabbitmq.config.example#L467-L473

Comment: another Question, do you acknowledge the messages from the consumer or publisher ? and which prefetch value did you set for your channels

Comment: @basilisk tried to enable the background gc. Though, after altering the .config by uncommenting {background_gc_enabled, false} and {background_gc_target_interval, 60000}, won't start up anymore. Also tried `rabbitmqctl force_gc` but it seems it does not recognizes the force_gc

Comment: @basilisk the consumer manually acknowledges messages and has a prefetch value 1